# magnetically coupled inductor equations

Tags: mutual-inductance

[image]

How come the mutual inductance for the v1(t) equation has a negative sign and the mutual inductance for the v2(t) equation have a positive sign? I don't properly understand how the signs of the self and mutual inductance is derived, because from my understanding current into the dot means positive and out of the dot is negative, however here for v1 it would be different since they specify a negative polarity. But still I don't quite understand how we get the signs for the mutual inductance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a closer look at your diagram: -

[image]

\$i_1\$ and \$i_2 \$ are flowing away from their respective dots. This is not conventional for coupled inductors and so attracts a negative sign in your top formula.

Then the same argument applies to the lower formula but, there's an extra twist - \$v_2\$ is not following the correct dot convention with respect to \$v_1\$ - voltage \$v_1\$ **is** following the correct dot convention hence, the two negative inverted conventions produce a net positive result in your 2nd formula.